# What is for Ubuntu phones the equivalent to booting from a live USB?

Tags: backup, restore, tools, bq, cloning

Is there a feasible method to boot Ubuntu Touch - **on a bq E5** - to bootfrom the mmc card or a USB device ? I am searching for the equivalent to similar methods of desktop Linux, in order to:
- copy/restore partitions to/from images
- backup and restore.

What I want is a restorable image of the system.

I have looked quickly into the answers tagged "backup", and I did not see anything like that.
I want to play in the sandbox, but first I look if my Band-Aid is ready for use!
*Clonezilla* would be ideal for that, would it not?

Some points:

> I have a running system, so / is mounted, which means that  dd cannot make a real working image of it.
>
> Could I boot from a live USB, then I would use dd (I love also Clonezilla. Did I mention it before?).

Comment: ... I cannot tell if what you seek is like a LiveCD ? Do you want an installation? It is **not** possible to boot from anywhere that is not ROM on a phone-like device, unless you write your own (Complicated!) firmware to do this.